# pywin32 installation with python 3.3.5

Tags: python, pywin32

I am new to python and want to do some work with windows directories

When attempting to install `pywin32-219.win32-py3.3.exe` on my machine I have the following error:

```
Python version 3.3 is required which was not found in the directory.
```

I know I have python 3.3.5 and 3.4 installed and running on my machine, V3.4 is associeted with the command line as well.

Am i correct in assuming the package I downloaded should install and run with python v3.3.5?
What could be causing the installer to conflict?

Comment: This looks like it is a problem with build 219 as build 218 detected python V3.3.5. Now i need to work out how to submit a bug report..

Comment: Because pywin32 look at registry and found 3.4 as a current python version.  So, you need pywin32 for python 3.4.

Comment: Python-3.3.5 is correctly named and placed ? it should be C:/Python33. It may be a problem if it's not. And check your python 3.3 version, is  it 32 bit ? the python and pywin32 should be the same bit rate.

Comment: It was the correct version of python (64 bit) with the correct file structure. However the pywin version I downloaded for buil 219 was 32 bit (at a guess) where as the build 218 version has '-amd64' in the file name